# Different Margin in First Page for DOCX

Tags: html, css, coldfusion, docx, cfml

My question is : I have word document i need to convert as html/css. How can i make different margin in my first page. 
Thanks for your helps

This is my code

```
<cfcontent type="application/msword">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myDoc.doc">
<html>
<title></title>
<style>
}
@page Section1{
    size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:0in 0in 0in 0in;
    mso-paper-source:0;
}
div.Section1{
    page:Section1;
}
@page Section2{
    size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;
    mso-paper-source:0;
}
div.Section2{
    page:Section2;
}
div.pageBreak {
  page-break-before:always;
</style>
</head>
<body style='tab-interval:.5in'>
    <div class="Section1" style="margin: 0in 0in 0in 0in;">
        Something page 1
        <div class="pageBreak"></div>   
    </div>
    <div class="Section2">
        Something page 2
        <div class="pageBreak"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Nothing first page remains the same as the second page

Comment: Syntax errors: Missing a } at the end of div.pagebreak, and you have 2 </script> tags.

Comment: @Mike, by `</script>` do you mean `</style>`?

Comment: @DanBracuk, yes, my bad.

Comment: İ changed that but still nothing happen. Idk what should i do